# Pull Random Attachments With Pagination

Tags: images, pages, pagination, gallery

I want to make a archive page that pulls in all uploaded images to the site. I am using the current script. Its paginating somewhat but not showing all the images. Showing around 90 out of 140.

```
     <?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>'8','paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); ?> 

 <?php
    if ( $images = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page'=>'8',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
    {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, postgallery );
            $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
            $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );

            if (!empty($imageDescription)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$imageDescription .'"><img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt=""  /></a>';
} else { echo '


<div class="span3_3">
<div class="widget">
                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <a href="' .get_attachment_link($image->ID). '" class="view-back" style="display: none;"></a>
                                    <img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
'; }    }
    } else {
        echo "No Image";
    } ?>
</div>
<div class='pagination pagination-centered'><ul><li>

<!--Pagination-->
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>

 </li></ul></div>
```

Comment: You've left out the most important part-- the code for `since83_pagination()`. Pretty sure I know the problem already though...

Comment: The code works fine for the other pages calling posts. I modded the post above. Seems i got it to work but the pagination just copies from the posts. Like the index page has 5 pages, its also showing 5 pages for the attachment page even though its only 3 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your `since83_pagination()` function is assuming the main query-- `$wp_query`-- but you are needing to paginate something very different. You need to be paginating the results in `$attachments` which you are retrieving with [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). That was my guess as soon as I saw this question.

You are going to need to rethink this. There are two options that come to mind.

If you are happy with passing pagination data in the URL use [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). That is probably the easiest option. [I have written a few answers on using `paginate_links`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21376%20paginate_links)

Your other option is to use a filter on [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). I do not have working code to post but I expect that this will be harder.

I would say, figure out which route you want to go, get started, and post your new code. I will edit the answer in light of the new code.

Comment: Ok updated. The current code is somewhat working. Showing around 90 images when there should be about 140. You can see i changed the entire loop, i liked the old loop i had better but couldn't get it to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress version 4.5 or greater, you can take advantage of the built-in MySQL function `RAND(n)` along with its seed value. As long as you pass the same `n` on each query, you will get the same set of random posts.

As an example:

```
$randomN = 123456;

$posts = get_posts(array(
    //... arguments here
    'orderby' => "rand($randomN)"
));
```

Read more about the `RAND(n)` function in the [docs](http://$randomN%20=%20rand(1,%2010000);%20%20$posts%20=%20get_posts(array(%20%20%20%20%20//...%20arguments%20here%20%20%20%20%20'orderby'%20=%3E%20%22rand($randomN)%22%20));).